# Laravel 5.7 Pagination URL (Change / Pretty)

Tags: php, laravel, url, pagination, friendly-url

I know there is so many threads out there regarding this topic but i worked through all of 'em and couldnt get it to work still and im stuck for a week now.

What i have: I am using laravel 5.7 and I do a Query on the Database to fetch all "posts" and then use the laravel pagination method on it. The URL given though is always appended with "?page=" and this is to be removed.
I found some stuff on Github which is no longer maintained and only roughly commented as i am fairly a beginner this is pretty hard for me to achieve.

If you do not know what I mean by now let me get thorough:
I registered a Route

```
Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index')
```

and in my PostsController I have

```
    public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::paginate(2);
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));               
}
```

This returns a working pagination, with the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?page=2

id love to have it http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/2
(I know, laravel thinks this is the second post from the database or so ive heard but i use slugnames for the single posts)
Well if i would be more experienced I am pretty sure its not hard to remove the ?page= from the URL or what other methods are out there. Maybe a redirect works? I am very happy to hear some (please well explained for me) answers.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If you want a pretty url for paginate use spatie/laravel-paginateroute

Comment: That is the above mentioned no longer maintained github link i found, it seems pretty hard to achieve. there it is written that it registers the route users, i use posts and not users or do i misunderstand something here?

Comment: EDIT: i got this working thats super nice. Now i just need the numbers because right now i only have prev and next buttons. but i need like pagenumbers and i think this might help but i dont understand it.  public function addPageQuery($url, $page, $full = false)